# Date difference calculation command

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

I have date in the format of 10/2/23. How can I get the difference of 10/2/23 to todays date? Please advise.

Comment: duplicates: [Quickly calculate date differences](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/24626/44425), [Calculate time difference between two dates](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/539854/44425), [Date Difference Calculation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/317139/44425)...

Comment: is that day month year or month day year?

Comment: see also [Unix: how to get number of days from a given date like 10Dec2022](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/740516/unix-how-to-get-number-of-days-from-a-given-date-like-10dec2022)

Comment: This question does not show the first step effort. Perhaps ChatGPT make this all for you.

Answer (score 0):

Time diff in integral seconds or integral days:

```
$ echo $(($(date +%s -d "10/2/23") - $(date +%s)))
11485596
$ echo $((($(date +%s -d "10/2/23") - $(date +%s))/(24*60*60)))
132
```

Comment: Thank you that worked.